# iptables rules are not in action

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a iptable rule file, on the INPUT chain I have

```
-A INPUT -i em1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 54000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i em1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i em1 -p udp -m udp --dport 54000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct 
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

then I `iptables-restore < rule_file`
and I started a UDP server on port 30000 which is not the allowed UDP port `54000`
but the UDP server still get incoming UDP packets on 30000
what's wrong with this?

BTW, `iptables -L -n` , I get:

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination 
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:54000
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:30000
    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:54000
    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ES
    TABLISHED
    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    INPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    INPUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0
```

I use nmap from another machine to probe this machine

```
nmap -port 30000
```

or

```
nmap -port 54000
```

the results show that these two ports are closed!

Comment: No rule actually drop or reject anything. Add one or check the policy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
```

Your rules never match as you're accepting everything

Check the packets which matches with:

```
iptables -nvL
```

EDIT etagenklo:
iptables go through all rules in a chain from top to bottom. If no rule is matching your packet, iptables will do what is defined as policy for the chain (in your case, this is ACCEPT)

To change your policy: `iptables -P CHAIN RULE`

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: I don't get it. If the line `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)` decide everything, what are the following rules used for?

Comment: In this exemple: nothing. Defining policy to accept and adding rules which jump to accept doesn't do anything. This makes sense if your are redirecting to another chain (a custom one for exemple)

Comment: @misteryes: maxxvw is right. What iptables does is the following: it will go through all rules in a chain from top to bottom. If no rule is matching your packet, iptables will do what is defined as policy for the chain (in your case, this is ACCEPT).

Comment: so how to modify the iptables rules?

Comment: -> see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, when you probe ports with nmap/telnet and getting the "closed" or "connection refused" or similar errors, it means you maybe doesn't have allowed the port OR you have the port allowed but no service listening on it.

I would personally write the rules this way:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT //if you want allow "familiar" packets
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i em1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 54000 -j ACCEPT //the interface is optional if your pc has only one network card
-A INPUT -i em1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i em1 -p udp -m udp --dport 54000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct 
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
```

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: answer update :)

Comment: why do you change the order? I tried your version, still the UDP server still get incoming UDP packets on 30000

Comment: BTW, what is INPUT_direct and INPUT_ZONES?

Comment: INPUT_ZONES can be accessed if INPUT_direct contains a -j RETURN.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I forgot that. :)

Comment: @misteryes I changed the order just for performance reasons. With the rules, as you'we written them, it shouldn't have any side effects. But I don't know what is written in the INPUT_direct and INPUT_ZONES chains so it could have some impact on the `-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT` rule. The same situation is with the conntrack module - if you want just watch ESTABLISHED,RELATED state, conntrack is not necessarry.

Do not forget before INPUT there is also PREROUTING chain. The problem may lay there.

Answer (score 0):

Change your policy for the chain to DROP:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Of course you will have to make sure that there's an ACCEPT rule for everything you need.

Explanation:

iptables will check all the rules inside a chain if they match for your packet. If no rule is matching, the policy for the chain gets executed.

So this should be the standard configuration for a firewall: You want it to accept everything which is specified in a rule and drop everything else.